# How to aggregate data for each day of the week?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, aggregate

I have a log of sign-in data for my local gym. I'd like to provide some visualizations for typical visitors in a given day/week/month.

Essentially, I need to aggregate the total visitors in each day. Then I'd like to show typical number of visitors for each Sunday, or mean/min/max of each month.

I'm having a tough time trying to group this data and wondering if anyone can assist?

**Here's what the data looks like:**

PS The columns got screwed up in this question. They got shifted left and an index column was made at the start.

```
| Visit Date | Visit Time | Member ID | Membership Name |          Ent          |          y Access           | Timestamp  |       Weekday       |   Month   |          |
|------------|------------|-----------|-----------------|-----------------------|-----------------------------|------------|---------------------|-----------|----------|
|          0 | 2016-12-01 | 19:08:41  |          5078.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-01 19:08:41 | Thursday  | December |
|          1 | 2016-12-01 | 19:08:42  |          5078.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-01 19:08:42 | Thursday  | December |
|          2 | 2016-12-02 | 8:57:31   |          5354.0 | Personal Training     |                             | Successful | 2016-12-02 08:57:31 | Friday    | December |
|          4 | 2016-12-04 | 9:02:24   |          5078.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-04 09:02:24 | Sunday    | December |
|          6 | 2016-12-05 | 16:54:01  |          5146.0 | *ZDNU* Unlimited Mont | ly Membership (In Person... | Successful | 2016-12-05 16:54:01 | Monday    | December |
|          7 | 2016-12-05 | 16:54:03  |          5146.0 | *ZDNU* Unlimited Mont | ly Membership (In Person... | Successful | 2016-12-05 16:54:03 | Monday    | December |
|         10 | 2016-12-06 | 16:40:49  |          5069.0 | 1 Month Unlimited Mem | ership - DD                 | Successful | 2016-12-06 16:40:49 | Tuesday   | December |
|         12 | 2016-12-06 | 16:47:33  |          5146.0 | *ZDNU* Unlimited Mont | ly Membership (In Person... | Successful | 2016-12-06 16:47:33 | Tuesday   | December |
|         13 | 2016-12-06 | 16:47:34  |          5146.0 | *ZDNU* Unlimited Mont | ly Membership (In Person... | Successful | 2016-12-06 16:47:34 | Tuesday   | December |
|         14 | 2016-12-07 | 17:03:35  |          5078.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-07 17:03:35 | Wednesday | December |
|         18 | 2016-12-08 | 16:51:38  |          5069.0 | 1 Month Unlimited Mem | ership - DD                 | Successful | 2016-12-08 16:51:38 | Thursday  | December |
|         22 | 2016-12-10 | 8:59:42   |          5078.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-10 08:59:42 | Saturday  | December |
|         24 | 2016-12-10 | 10:03:26  |          5143.0 | 12 Visit Punchcard (C | sh/Moneris Only)            | Successful | 2016-12-10 10:03:26 | Saturday  | December |
|         27 | 2016-12-12 | 6:58:27   |          5048.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-12 06:58:27 | Monday    | December |
|         29 | 2016-12-12 | 16:55:08  |          5078.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-12 16:55:08 | Monday    | December |
|         31 | 2016-12-12 | 16:58:47  |          5078.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-12 16:58:47 | Monday    | December |
|         32 | 2016-12-13 | 16:51:20  |          5146.0 | *ZDNU* Unlimited Mont | ly Membership (In Person... | Successful | 2016-12-13 16:51:20 | Tuesday   | December |
|         33 | 2016-12-13 | 16:51:20  |          5146.0 | *ZDNU* Unlimited Mont | ly Membership (In Person... | Successful | 2016-12-13 16:51:20 | Tuesday   | December |
|         38 | 2016-12-14 | 6:59:18   |          5043.0 | Personal Training     |                             | Successful | 2016-12-14 06:59:18 | Wednesday | December |
|         39 | 2016-12-14 | 17:00:58  |          5078.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-14 17:00:58 | Wednesday | December |
|         41 | 2016-12-14 | 17:01:15  |          5061.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-14 17:01:15 | Wednesday | December |
|         45 | 2016-12-15 | 16:52:12  |          5073.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-15 16:52:12 | Thursday  | December |
|         46 | 2016-12-15 | 16:52:13  |          5073.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-15 16:52:13 | Thursday  | December |
|         47 | 2016-12-15 | 16:52:28  |          5146.0 | *ZDNU* Unlimited Mont | ly Membership (In Person... | Successful | 2016-12-15 16:52:28 | Thursday  | December |
|         48 | 2016-12-15 | 16:52:28  |          5146.0 | *ZDNU* Unlimited Mont | ly Membership (In Person... | Successful | 2016-12-15 16:52:28 | Thursday  | December |
|         49 | 2016-12-15 | 16:57:39  |          5069.0 | 1 Month Unlimited Mem | ership - Student            | Successful | 2016-12-15 16:57:39 | Thursday  | December |
|         57 | 2016-12-16 | 16:46:55  |          5310.0 | Personal Training     |                             | Successful | 2016-12-16 16:46:55 | Friday    | December |
|         58 | 2016-12-16 | 16:46:56  |          5310.0 | Personal Training     |                             | Successful | 2016-12-16 16:46:56 | Friday    | December |
|         59 | 2016-12-16 | 16:47:12  |          5310.0 | Personal Training     |                             | Successful | 2016-12-16 16:47:12 | Friday    | December |
|         60 | 2016-12-16 | 17:00:09  |          5061.0 | Regular Monthly Membe | ship                        | Successful | 2016-12-16 17:00:09 | Friday    | December |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group by weekday (M/T/W/T/F/S/S)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864691/pandas-group-by-weekday-m-t-w-t-f-s-s)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample